# how to get image name and alt attr and then find and replace characters in it

Tags: jquery, replace

While i am trying to generate the names for the images in my blog using jscript

```
$img.attr('title', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
```

i am getting the name of the image containing dashes and plus. My question is to get the name without dasshes and plus and insterd of characters i want to get spaces. can any one make it possibble.
the entire code looks like this

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('img').each(function()
{
var $img = $(this);
var filename = $img.attr('src')
$img.attr('title', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
$img.attr('alt', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
$img.attr('title', filename.replace("+"," "));
});
});
//]]>
</script>
```

This is the complete script and i wanted to know how to avoid special char from the image name while getting it and replacing the special char with spaces.

It must be placed just after  section in a blogger html code.

Comment: `$img.attr('title', title.replace("+"," "));` title (the second one) is not defined.

Comment: Can you give an example of the filename and an example of what its title would be - because your question is confusing.

Comment: Now check it i have provided the complete script.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HGLAx/3/)**

It looks like you're trying to get the basename and then replace - or + with space, e.g. given `http://somedomain.com/images/some+image-here.jpg` you want `some image here`

The following takes the basename, replaces dashes and pluses with spaces and removes the numbers.

```
$('img').each(function(){
  var bn=$(this).attr('src').replace(/[0-9]|^.*\/|\.[^.]*$/g, '').replace(/[\+|\-]/g,' ');
  $(this).attr('title', bn).attr('alt',bn);
});
```

or if you want to keep the .jpg

```
var bn=$(this).attr('src').replace(/[0-9]|^.*\/|\.*$/g, '').replace(/[\+|\-]/g,' ');
```

Comment: Now check the script i have provided the complete script.

Comment: But it's replacing the first + sigh only what about the next once

Comment: Probably it's yes. Do some changes in my script and give me the full script. i really need it.

Comment: it's changing the first plus only what about the next one and the after that one. just tell me how to make the other once to spaces.

Comment: what about blocking of numbers.it's allowing numbers. How to block them this will be the last question.

Comment: You tell me in the form of .replace('0-9',''); like this. is this correct

Comment: **+1** Excellent Answer.  For user, study [**this**](http://alpha.jsfiddle.net/PNhP3/)

Comment: i found my answer tnx dude

Comment: Great. I've added it to the code above and given an example on jsfiddle.